# Error: duplicate list records when got from API that made from Spring Boot and SQL Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I created a store procedure in SQL Server and it working fine like the following:

```
exec udf_get_gio_hang_by_id_khach_hang @id_khach_hang='KH00003368'
```

and the result is 2 records like the following:

[image]

My purpose is create a API to get list of above record.So I create API by Spring Boot like the following:
First I create a model `GioHang.java`

```
@Entity
public class GioHang implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    private String id_khach_hang;
    
    
    private String id_xe;
    private int so_luong;
    
    //setter,getter

}
```

Then I created a repository interface `GioHangRepo.java`

```
@Repository
public interface GioHangRepo extends JpaRepository<GioHang,String> {
@Query(value = "{call udf_get_gio_hang_by_id_khach_hang(:id_khach_hang)}",nativeQuery = true)
    public List<GioHang> get_list_gio_hang_via_id_khach_hang(@Param("id_khach_hang")  String id_khach_hang);
}
```

Next I created a service `GioHangService.java`

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class GioHangService {
    @Autowired
    private GioHangRepo gioHangRepo;

    public List<GioHang> getGioHangById_khach_hang(String id_khach_hang)
    {
        return this.gioHangRepo.get_list_gio_hang_via_id_khach_hang(id_khach_hang);
    }
}
```

Finally, I created a API in   `GioHangResource.java`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/gio_hang")
public class GioHangResource {
    @Autowired
    private GioHangService gioHangService;
    
    @GetMapping("/getGioHangById_khach_hang/{id_khach_hang}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<GioHang>> getGioHangById(@PathVariable("id_khach_hang") String id_khach_hang)
    {
        List<GioHang> gh = this.gioHangService.getGioHangById_khach_hang(id_khach_hang);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(gh,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I test API in swagger but I got the list of duplicate records like the following:

I don't know why records in list all are the same with the first record ?

[image]

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this error is because I set primary for `id_khach_hang`and `id_xe` in SQL Server but just make `@Id` for one of them
If that:
Solution 1:Make `@Id` for both `id_khach_hang`and `id_xe`
Solution 2:You can add  a another column like `Id_record` and then make primary key to it ,and make foreign key for `id_khach_hang`and `id_xe`.and remember make `@Id` for `id_record`

Comment: yeah it is what I want.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to the fact that you're using the `id_khach_hang` as a primary key, which should be unique, thing that doesn't happen in your case. You should have a column that should have unique values and use it for the @Id property.

Also, please don't use the snake notation when writing code in java, it makes things so ugly and hard to understand.